# MVC 5 View dynamically add or delete list of model

Tags: razor, dynamic, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

I have a model

```
public class DeModel
{
  public string id{get;set;}
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public List<AdressesModel>{get;set;}
}

public class AdressesModel
{
 public string id{get;set;}
 public string line1{get;set;}
 public string line2{get;set;}
 public string hometown{get;set;}
 public string city{get;set;}
 public string country{get;set;}
}
```

In my view, user should be able to add or delete addresses and I should be able to get the final list on the post back.

Js is one way , but it is too complicated , I have to keep track of the indexes and I need to change alot when the model changes.

I see that editorfortemplates with ajax call is an option but couldn't figure out how to do that .

How can I do this other than JS ?

Comment: You will need javascipt/jquery one way or the other. You can look at the [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/) helper. Refer [this tutorial](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) for an example

Comment: And for a pure client side solution, refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308)

Comment: You can do that using KnockoutJS